# java.exe exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin, proguard

I'm using vs 2017 and xamarin.forms.

I'm getting the error "java.exe exited with 1" in the release mode with ProGuard turned on. (in the debug & without proguard its doing fine) It's a common question, i know , but i've tried all the variants and it still doesnt work.

1.tried to update proguard to 5.3 version manualy

2.to update jdk 8, to install either x64 or x86 or both

3.to change the java memory to 1g , 4g, 500 m

4.to turn on multi-desk

5. to edit the proguard-android.txt by adding

   -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

   -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

(These just ignore proguard, google play doesnt accept it.)

ANY OTHER VARIANTS HERE?

```
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.Object zzb(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzu            
there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager: can't find referenced method 'void zzb(boolean,java.lang.Object)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzu
there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.    
com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task$Builder: can't find referenced method 'void zzb(boolean,java.lang.Object)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzu  
com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
```